# Connect with PrincipalContext to another domain

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, directoryservices

Our customer his server is located in the "a.local" domain.
There is an domain trust to "b.local".

From my application we allow the user to choose a domain first, and then fill in their credentials.
In the configuration of our application there is a config for both domains, where a service account is set to authenticate with.

When a user want to login with a "b.local" user, we are now seeing that the `PrincipalContext` just connects to the domain controller of "a.local".

As a test, we even filled in the domain controller in the constructor.

```
Dim oDomainContext As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DC.b.local", "svc_acc", "pwd")
```

After that we printed out the `oDomainContext.ConnectedServer`.
And we got that it was connected to "DC.a.local".

Is it allowed to connect to a domain controller outside the domain of where the service is in?
If not, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Maybe it's a DNS thing. Does both "DC.a.local" and "DC.b.local" resolve to the same IP address, and that server identifies itself as "DC.a.local"?

Comment: I did another debug, and I found that there was a case sensitive search what domain to use. Since the case was different, it did a fallback to the first found config. So the above issue is not an issue.
Thanks for the response again @GabrielLuci.